# IBM WebSphere MQ JNDI Binding

Tags: cluster-computing, ibm-mq

When we are using the direct connection to MQ then Active Passive MQ clustering is possible. I have doubt when we will use the JNDI binding for MQ Objects Like Queue Manager,Queue etc. Is it possible to have MQ clustering.

Because I am not sure how to bind the queue connection factory in this case.  As there will be virtual IP address on Active node. Will I be able to bind the objects without Virtual IP address on passive node.

Answer (score 0):

> When we are using the direct connection to MQ then Active Passive MQ clustering is possible.

I think you need to read up on HA Active/Passive because it sounds like you are thinking of HA Active/Active.

> Is it possible to have MQ clustering.

MQ Clustering has nothing to do with your question.  If you want to use MQ clustering, then use it rather than point-to-point messaging.  When you implement MQ clustering, then ALL of your queue managers are running (i.e. Active).

> As there will be virtual IP address on Active node. Will I be able to bind the objects without Virtual IP address on passive node.

Again, it sounds like you want Active/Active and not Active/Passive.